# Can you dump out a json file with duplicate keys in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a script, which loads a json file, and if it has duplicates, adds "_x" to the duplicate key, where x is an integer that goes up every time it dettects the key. Then it saves the indexes of the duplicates to a file. I want to be able to later dump the json file with the duplicate keys insterted back. Is there any way to do this other than turning the json to raw string and editing that?

Comment: You cannot have a JSON structure or Python dictionary with duplicate keys

Comment: Of course you can have a `json` file with duplicate keys and you can read the file and print it.

Comment: I don't think any parser/stringifier will account for it, since (while it's technically allowed in json) it's not a useful feature at all. So yeah, you'll probably have to reverse `_x` additions from the json string

Comment: In case it's not obvious, it's technically not hard to do what you are asking, but the result will be invalid JSON. The purpose of using a standard serialization format is to have well-defined behavior; by forcing undefined behavior, you are giving up this crucial benefit.

Comment: Json does not explocitly say, that you can't do that. It says you shouldn't but it doesn't disallow it. I'm building a tool, that the user can input a json into. If the user wants to have duplicate json, I will not stop them

Comment: You can trivially decode an object as a list of key/value pairs instead of a `dict`: `json.loads('{"a": 1, "a": 2}', object_pairs_hook=lambda x: x)`. Encoding a list of key/value pairs with non-unique keys as an object is a little trickier. (Though if your process eliminates all duplicates, you just pass it to `dict`: `json.dumps(dict(list_of_key_value_pairs))`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom encoder that converters dictionaries to strings for output, e.g.,:

```py
import json


# our dictionary with "duplicates" to be changed
d = {"x_1": 1, "x_2": 2}

# create a dummy dictionary class to store the dictionary
class DummyDict:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
        self.keys = list(d.keys())
        self.values = list(d.values())
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < len(self.d):
            key = self.keys[self.i]
            self.i += 1
            return key
 
        raise StopIteration

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.d)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.d[item]


# create a custom encoder class to encode DummyDict objects
class DuplicateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, DummyDict):
             dstr = "{"
             for i, key in enumerate(obj):
                 # get encoded version
                 encoded = str(DuplicateEncoder().encode(obj[key]))

                 if isinstance(obj[key], DummyDict):
                     # remove quotation marks at ends
                     encoded = encoded[1:-1]
 
                 # check for keys containing underscores
                 if "_" in key:
                     # take the part before the underscore
                     dstr += f"{key.split('_')[0]}: {encoded}"
                 else:
                     dstr += f"{key}: {encoded}"
                 if i < len(obj) - 1:
                     dstr += ", "
             dstr += "}"
             return dstr
    
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


# if your dictionary is nested and contains other dictionaries then
# they'll all need converting into DummyDict objects, which this
# function will do
def converter(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        dtmp = d.copy()
        for key in d.keys():
            if isinstance(d[key], dict):
                dtmp[key] = converter(d[key])
        dd = DummyDict(dtmp)
    else:
        dd = d
    return dd


# put you dictionary into a DummyDict
dd = converter(d)

dstr = json.dumps(dd, cls=DuplicateEncoder)

# write to file (if you use json.dump you'll get "'s at the start and end
with open("test.json", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(dstr[1:-1])
```

You unfortunately have to create the `DummyDict` class to hold the dictionary, and this can't be subclassed from a `dict`, otherwise the encoder will automatically use its dictionary parser for the encoding.

Comment: Which one should I edit to make it work with nested json? I think its the __init__ but I'm not sure

Comment: You'd need some kind of recursive function that goes though the nested dictionary and converts any `dict`s to `DummyDict`s. I'll add a function into the answer.

Comment: I've now added a function `converter` that will convert a nested dictionary, such that all dictionaries within it become `DummyDict` classes. The encoder should then work for these dictionaries.

Comment: With d = `"{"x_1": 1, "x_2": {"x_3":3}}"` i get `"{x: 1, x: <__main__.DummyDict object at 0x000001B6C0771F10>}"`

Comment: I've made a change to the `DuplicateEncoder` class so this it should now work with you example.

Comment: Or maybe not quite yet! I just need to check something!

Comment: In fact, it should work as is. If I try it with and initial `d = {"x_1": 1, "x_2": {"x_3": 3}, "x_4": [12, 435]}`, then the `dstr` value is `"{x: 1, x: {x: 3}, x: [12, 435]}"`.

Comment: Would this work with lists in the nest aswell, if I added ```elif isinstance(d[key], list): for item in d[key]: dtmp[key] = converter(d[key])```

Comment: It should already work with lists in the nest without any changes.

Comment: d = {"x_1": 1, "x_2": {"x_3":["x_4", {"x_5":3}]}} gives `{x: 1, x: {x: [\\\"x_4\\\", {\\\"x_5\\\": 3}]}}`

Comment: Yeah, that won't work as "x_4" is not a dictionary key. To have that work you'd need some sort of `DummyList` class as well and have a statement in the `DuplicateEncoder` that deals specifically with those objects.

Comment: yea, that x_4 was my mistake, was only meant to add x_5